# How to solve .htaccess issue for a live server that's working on localhost?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

It's working perfectly on localhost but not working on client live server. I used this code to rewrite the url:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>         
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L] 
</IfModule>
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Very broad question. What's the actual problem? Are you receiving a normal 404 Not Found? Check that mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Hello Mike, Thanks for your comment . I am not getting that . when i am clicking on  any link it's showing me like http://error404.000webhost.com/?

Comment: It's technically the same - 000webhost uses their own page for 404s, it's a way to market their offering. There's a good chance they don't have mod_rewrite enabled, or simply don't allow the use of htaccess files.

Comment: And I checked the mod_rewrite is enable on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [FAQ entry](https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/do-you-support-htaccess-what-should-i-know-about-it-16) on 000webhost's website, you need to add a `RewriteBase` as they use virtual home user directories.

So, add the applicable directive below `RewriteEngine`:

```bash
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>         
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You are right but. It's not working on this free webhosting site. As they are not allowing the the use of htaccess files. But I tried another  purchase hosting  and it's working perfectly.

Comment: They do allow htaccess files... But anyway, glad you purchased hosting, it is the better way to go. ;-)